# Forecasting date in the future

Tags: python, pandas, forecasting

> Hi there,
> I am a really neophyte dealing with Python scripts however I’ve been trying to perform some univariate forecasting of solar radiation using some code I found in Github [1](https://github.com/sgautam666/Time_Series_Forecasting_of_Solar_Irradiance/blob/main/LSTM_Modelling_All_Location.ipynb). The process is running well as I get results for future dates in an hourly frequency (24 hours) but I am stuck when trying to get results for several days at the same time. For example, when I set out_steps= 78 (for 3 days in the future) I get results just for the 3rd day and I would like to have results for the whole time span. Could you please give some hints to solve this situation?

```
def model(X_train, y_train, n_steps, n_features, epochs, batch_size):
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(layers.LSTM(100, activation='relu', 
                              input_shape=(n_steps, n_features),
                              return_sequences=True))  
    model.add(layers.LSTM(50, activation='relu'))
    model.add(layers.Dense(1))
    model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
    print(model.summary())
    
    history = model.fit(X_train, y_train,  epochs=epochs, 
                            batch_size=batch_size, verbose=2)

    IPython.display.clear_output()
    
    return model, history
model_24h, history_24h = model(x_train_24h, y_train_24h, n_steps=24, n_features=1, epochs=100, batch_size=100)

def prediction_list2(model, scaled_ts, indexed_ts, frequency, in_steps, out_steps, n_features, batch_size):
    '''
    A function to create future forecast dates
    scaled_ts : training time series with scalar applied
    indexed_ts : time series with datetime index
    frequency : years/months/weeks/days/hours/minutes/seconds
    '''
    pred_list = []
    batch = scaled_ts[-n_steps:].reshape((1, n_steps, n_features))
    for i in range(out_steps):
        if batch_size == 1:
            pred_list.append(model.predict(batch)[0][0])   #need to be careful about the level!
        else:
            pred_list.append(model.predict(batch)[0])
            
        batch = np.append(batch[:,1:,:],[[pred_list[i]]],axis=1)   
    
    if frequency =='years':
        add_dates = [indexed_ts.index[-1] + DateOffset(years=x) for x in range(0,out_steps+1) ]
    elif frequency == 'months':
        add_dates = [indexed_ts.index[-1] + DateOffset(months=x) for x in range(0,out_steps+1) ]
    elif frequency == 'weeks':
        add_dates = [indexed_ts.index[-1] + DateOffset(weeks=x) for x in range(0,out_steps+1) ]  
    elif frequency == 'days':
        add_dates = [indexed_ts.index[-1] + DateOffset(days=x) for x in range(0,out_steps+1) ]
    elif frequency == 'hours':
        add_dates = [indexed_ts.index[-1] + DateOffset(hours=x) for x in range(0,out_steps+1) ]    
    future_dates = pd.DataFrame(index=add_dates[1:],columns=indexed_ts.columns)
    
    return pred_list, future_dates

pred_list_72h, future_dates_72h = prediction_list2(model_24h, train_24h_scaled, train_h_all, 
                                            frequency='hours', in_steps=24, out_steps=72, n_features=1, batch_size=100)
final_predict_72h = pd.DataFrame(scaler_24h.inverse_transform(pred_list_24h),
                          index=future_dates_72h[-n_steps:].index, columns=['Prediction'])
final_proj_72h = pd.concat([train_h_all, final_predict_72h], axis=1)
```

> VARIABLES

train_24h_scaled---array of float--- (96360, 1)

train_h_all---Dataframe--(96360, 1)

scaler_24h---MinMaxScaler

pred_list_24h---list---24---[Numpy Array]

Comment: Could you fix your indenting please so that your code is valid?

Comment: The indentation is important in `python` like curly braces in other languages. If this is incorrect the code will be out of its intended scope. Please correct this when asking the question.